# Solve Spherical Shell for Radius given Thickness and Volume

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I'm looking to calculate the outer radius of a spherical shell of a desired volume and thickness.  I don't know if the years have knocked some obvious obstacle out of my perception, but here's what i'm struggling with.
Given: Thickness T, Radii R and r, and Volume V and the following relationships:
$$
T=R-r
$$
$$
V=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 - \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3
$$
How do I solve for R in terms of V and T?

I get as far as:

$$
\frac{3V}{4\pi}=R^3-(R-T)^3
$$
Which comes down to...
$$
\frac{3V}{4\pi} = 3R^2-3RT+T^2
$$

Which i'm lost on breaking apart.  For more clarification, this is supposed to be just a fun exercise for a D&D game.  The rules i'm working with are limited by volume, and the integrity of created objects would be limited by thickness.  Thus, these are the terms i wanted to control, and then calculate the resulting outer radius of what the character can create.

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Comment: If your last line is correct, then simply use the quadratic formula here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to do it (except you have an algebraic error in your last equation, which you could deduce from dimensional analysis). Now you have a simple quadratic in $R$: $$R^2 - TR + \left(\frac{T^2}{3} - \frac{V}{4\pi T}\right) = 0.$$

Use the quadratic formula to solve it, and pick the positive root.

$$R = \frac{T + \sqrt{T^2 - 4\left(\frac{T^2}{3} - \frac{V}{4\pi T}\right)}}{2} = \frac{T + \sqrt{T^2 - \frac{4}{3}T^2 + \frac{V}{\pi T}}}{2} = \frac{T+\sqrt{\frac{V}{\pi T} -\frac{T^2}{3} }}{2}$$

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  After @Sawarnik's comment, my next question was exactly answered by this.  Thanks!

Comment: @user146407 Of course, as a DM I would probably rule that the interior of your object is included in the 1 cu ft / caster level limit of *minor creation* even though it isn't solid, so this doesn't actually help you that much.

Comment: That's fair.  We've been looser with it due to the nature of the campaign and the characters other limitations.  

More on topic, the big lesson for me was that c in the quadratic can be as complex as it needs to be, but if at all possible, simplify b.  It's been a long time since i did this routinely.

Comment: @user146407 Also, assuming you have $T$ in inches, remember to convert to feet before applying this formula, or the answer you get won't make any sense.